# Output is zero when dividing?

Tags: java, math, division

Maybe I can't see obvious thing but:

```
int x1 = 2;
int y1 = 4;
int x2 = 11;
int y2 = 7;
double res = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1);
System.out.println(res);
```

Output:

```
0.0
```

Why?

Comment: try `double res = (y2-y1)/((double)x2-x1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to initially define those variables as doubles and it should work.

Comment: you can cast the result to a `double` as well

Comment: @doublesharp casting the result is not sufficient but you can cast the first operand as well

Comment: @JanDvorak that's what I meant to say, but didn't.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is you're doing integer arithmetic.  You need a typecast in order to convert the numerator or denominator to floating point first (e.g.):

```
int x1 = 2;
int y1 = 4;
int x2 = 11;
int y2 = 7;
double res = (double)(y2-y1)/(x2-x1);
System.out.println(res);
```

If you do division on whole numbers, the result is truncated to the nearest whole number (which yields the same result as a floor operation).  For example:

```
0 / 2 == 0
1 / 2 == 0
2 / 2 == 1
3 / 2 == 1
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
int x1 = 2;
int y1 = 4;
int x2 = 11;
int y2 = 7;
double res = (double)(y2-y1)/(x2-x1);
System.out.println(res);
```

You have to box it "while" doing the operation, not after

Answer (score 0):

cast `(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)` to double like below:

```
                    int x1 = 2;
            int y1 = 4;
            int x2 = 11;
            int y2 = 7;
            double res = (double)(y2-y1)/(x2-x1);
            System.out.println(res);

Output: 0.3333333333333333
```