# How to update Progress Bar Percentage with Data Binding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I am unable to update ProgressBar progress with data binding.

Here's what I am doing -

- I have a model for holding ProgressBar current progress.

**ModelProgress.java**

```
public class ModelProgress extends BaseObservable {
    private int total;
    private int current;

    public void setCurrent(int current) {
        this.current = current;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.progress);
    }

    @Bindable
    public int getProgress() {
        return (current / total) * 100;
    }
}
```

**Please Note** I have made `getProgress() @Bindable` and notifying `BR.progress` on updation of value `current`. So that UI attached to `BR.progress` update when change in variable `current`.

In XML I tried to attach `ProgressBar` with variable `progress`.

```
<ProgressBar
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:progress="@{model.progress}"
    tools:progress="50" />
```

#### Problem

It's all set for me. Now when I call setCurrent() method, it should reflect on UI. Like `binding.getModel().setCurrent(50);`. But it doesn't.

Comment: make current as `ObservableField` also post ViewModel class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work unless `(current / total) * 100` is not returning zero each time.
The method returns 0, because when dividing two integer values, if denominator is greater than numerator then it returns 0. Check [the explained answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13338545/6891563) . You can change your `getProgress()` method's implementation.

```
public class ModelProgress extends BaseObservable {
    private int total=100;
    private int current;
    public void setCurrent(int current) {
        this.current = current;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.progress);
    }
    @Bindable
    public int getProgress() {
        return current * 100 / total;
    }
}
```

Also check you have to initialized `total` first. and check how are you calculating the progress.
  Make sure you should not forget to set model .

```
modelProgress=new ModelProgress();
mainBinding.setModel(modelProgress);
```

Comment: True!, getProgress() was returning 0, it worked when I changed it to `(int) (((float)current / (float)total) * 100);`.